# How to pass a string in Vue and have it treated as html

Tags: html, vue.js

I'm trying to pass the value for exp using the following code. However, the form of selectedChannel.explanation is " < b > channel name < / b > ". How can i get exp to show it as **channel name**?

```
computed: {
    channel: {
        get() {
            const selectedChannel = this.$store.getters.selectedChannel;
            return selectedChannel ? selectedChannel.explanation : '';
        }
```

Below is the partial of the template

```
<div class="channels">
      <textarea
      v-model="channel">
      </textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle, are you getting any error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any value given to input tag (also textarea) will be treated as a `string`. 
To show channel name in the `textarea` tag, you can do this

```
computed: {
    channel: {
        get() {
            const selectedChannel = this.$store.getters.selectedChannel;
            // using regex to match the text between "b" tag
            const channelName = selectedChannel.match("<b\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/b>")[1];
            return selectedChannel ? `<textarea>${channelName}</textarea>` : '';
        }
```

In template:

```
<div class="channels" v-html="channel">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the 'v-html' directive

Comment: i tried changing v-model to v-html, but it still doesn't show it that way, its still showing the bold tags

Comment: Could you put up a jsfiddle, most likely you are not passing a string to v-html but could be something else.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the v-html directive:

```
<div class="channels" v-html="channel">
</div>
```

Sample fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gmsa/qgq8vv90/)

Comment: hey, I'm sure this will throw compile error. This is syntactically wrong.Is this a feature of old Vue.js versions ?

Comment: You're right, I didn't know that feature was removed in Vue 2. v-html is the way to go. I edited my answer.